# What does %~1 do in this batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I found this code, but there are parts that I do not understand.

This is my code:

Main.bat:

```
@echo off
set "CallCount=0"
set "Mood="
set /P "Mood=Your mood is: "
call Receive.bat "%Mood%"
rem *Random stuff*
set "Food="
set /P "Food=The food you want is: "
call Receive.bat "%Food%"
set "CallCount="
```

Receive.bat:

```
@echo off  
set /A CallCount+=1           
if "CallCount"=="2" goto Call2   
if not "%~1"=="" echo %1     <----
*Random Stuff*                   |
goto :EOF                        |---What is %~1 doing in this area?
:Call2                           |
if not "%~1"=="" echo %1     <----
rem Commands for second call.
```

Edit: This is a file that uses the call command twice.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`%1` is the first argument from the invoking command line. If the passed argument has quotes around it, `%1` includes the quotes. Where as, `%~1` provides the argument value with quotes removed.

Helpful reference [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).